# React.js error :TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

Currently trying to make a MERN Stack web app from this tutorial : https://youtu.be/aibtHnbeuio
So I'am pretty new too the stack and don't know how to fix this...
help plz

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Post**
**C:/Users/I/Desktop/memories-pr/client/src/components/Posts/Post/Post.js:27**

```
  24 |     </Button>
  25 | </div>
  26 | <div className={classes.details}>
> 27 |     <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="h2">{post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag} `)}</Typography>
     |   28 | </div>
  29 | <CardContent>
  30 |     <Typography className={classes.title}  variant="h5" gutterBottom > {post.message} </Typography>
```

(anonymous function)
C:/Users/I/Desktop/memories-pr/client/src/actions/posts.js:8

```
 5 | try {
   6 |     const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();
   7 | 
>  8 |     dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data});
     | ^   9 | } catch (error) {
  10 |     console.log(error.message);
  11 | }
```

Comment: I guess it means that post.tags is undefined? Have you tried printing the "post" variable to the console, or inspecting it in a debugger?

Comment: It is basically saying that, your `post.tags` is `undefined`. Try checking if fetched data properly or check if your `post` has a property - `tags`.

Comment: post.tags && post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag} ` -  Add null check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by fetching `post` asynchronously, if that's the case then initially the value of `post` will remain `undefined` and you will be shown this error.

Use null propogation or conditional rendering to avoid this error:

```
<Typography 
    variant="body2" 
    color="textSecondary"    
   component="h2">
     {post?.tags?.map((tag) => `#${tag} `)}
</Typography>
```